# Mapping flat DB documents to nested classes in Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, morphia, jongo

I am porting a Java application that used to use Jongo to communicate with MongoDB to Morphia + new MongoDB Java Driver.

In the database there are flat documents like:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2e5b9b9b6e9753d4f11de"),
        "field1" : "foo",
        "field2" : "bar",
        "field3" : NumberLong("1455613369030"),
        "field4" : NumberLong("1455613369030"),
        "field5" : NumberLong(58),
        "field6" : NumberLong(1)
}
```

And there are **not** flat entity classes to store those documents in Java app, annotated using jackson to be usable with Jongo:

```
public class MyPOJOClass {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "foobar";

    @JsonProperty(value = "_id")
    private String id;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private FooBar foobar;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private MyLongs longs;

    // Constructor and other methods

    public static class FooBar {
        @JsonProperty(value = "field1")
        private String foo;
        @JsonProperty(value = "field2")
        private String bar;
        // Consteructor and other methods…
    }

    public static class MyLongs {
        @JsonProperty(value = "field3")
        private long first;
        @JsonProperty(value = "field4")
        private long second;
        // etc…
    }
}
```

Can I somehow port this exact structure to Morphia as is, **without** flattening the entity classes or expanding documents (so that `foo` and `bar` fields are in one embedded document and `LongNumber` fields in another document)?

I have not found any examples of the `@Embedded` annotation (the only one that looks relevant and gives some hope) to do such a thing. I want to end up with something like:

```
@Entity(MyPOJOClass.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class MyPOJOClass {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "foobar";

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @Embedded(_SOME_MAGIC_?)
    private FooBar foobar;
    @Embedded(_SOME_MAGIC_?)
    private MyLongs longs;

    // Constructor and other methods

    @Embedded(_SOME_MAGIC_?)
    public static class FooBar {
        @Property("field1")
        private String foo;
        @Property("field2")
        private String bar;
        // Consteructor and other methods…
    }

    @Embedded(_SOME_MAGIC_?)
    public static class MyLongs {
        @Property("field3")
        private long first;
        @Property("field4")
        private long second;
        // etc…
    }
}
```